# How to solve a functional equation?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is there any idea to solve the following
functional equation $f(2z)=2f(z)f(\pi/2-z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}.$

I have got $f(\pi-z)=f(z)$, and I also try to prove $f(z+2\pi)=f(z),$
but I fails.

In the case $f$ is holomorphic, I try to use the power series expansion.
But it seems the coefficients of $f(z)f(\pi/2-z)$ is not easy to determine,
which will involve many sums.

If we moreover assume $f'(z)=f(\frac{\pi}{2}-z).$ I can solve the problem
by considering the quotient $(f'(z)+if(z))/e^{iz}.$

I have found some special solutions $\sin((4k+1)z)$ and any finite products of them. I guess we can solve the problem by Fourier series, but the relation between the coeffcients will be very complicated.\

Let us restrict $f$ to $\mathbb{R},$ and the Fourier series of $f$ is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n \cos(nx)+b_n \sin(nx)).$$
We may assume $a_0=b_0.$ By computation, the coefficients of $f$ must satisfy the following equation
\begin{align*}
&\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty[a_k-(-1)^ka_0(a_{2k}-b_{2k})]\cos(2kx)+
\sum_{k=0}^\infty[b_k-(-1)^ka_0(a_{2k}+b_{2k})]\sin(2kx)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(b_{n-1}b_{2k+1}-a_{n-1}a_{2k+1}+a_nb_{2k}+b_n a_{2k})\sin((n+2k)x)\\\
&\quad +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(b_{n+1}b_{2k+1}+a_{n+1}a_{2k+1}+b_na_{2k}-a_n b_{2k})\sin((n-2k)x)\\\
&\quad +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(a_{n-1}b_{2k+1}+b_{n-1}a_{2k+1}+a_na_{2k}-b_n b_{2k})\cos((n+2k)x)\\\
&\quad +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(a_{n+1}b_{2k+1}-b_{n+1}a_{2k+1}+a_na_{2k}+b_n b_{2k})\cos((n-2k)x)\\\
&\quad + \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}(b_{0}b_{2k+1}+a_{0}a_{2k+1})\sin((2k+1)x)\\\
&\quad +\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(a_{0}b_{2k+1}-b_0a_{2k+1})\cos((2k+1)x)\\\
\end{align*}
By comparing the coefficients, we can get the relations of $a_n$ and $b_n.$
For example, consider the constant term, we have
$$a_0=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_{2k}^2+b_{2k}^2).$$
Thus, I have found all solutions under certain conditions of $f.$
(which gurantees the convergence of the Fouries series).

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Try trigonometry, as the $\pi/2$ hints.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I have consider the case $f$ is holomorphic and try to cinsider the value of $f(\pi/2^k)$, but get nothing

Comment: @FShrike I know $f(z)=sin(z)$ satisfies such equation, and I also consider the quotient $f(z)/sin(z).$ But also get nothing.

Comment: There might be a lot of solutions!

Comment: Notice that if you define $g(z) = 2f(z)$, then the formula reads $g(2z) = g(z)\,g(\pi/2-z)$. In particular, if $g_1$ and $g_2$ verify the equation, then $g_1\,g_2$ also verifies the equation.

Comment: Another interesting question might be: is there a strictly positive solution? If yes, then taking the logarithm, and rescaling gives that it is equivalent to the equation $u(2x) = u(x) + u(1-x)$

Comment: @LL3.14 I think the only strictly positive solution is $f(z)\equiv 1/2$ if the domain is all of $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: @LL3.14 Over $\mathbb{R},$ there are a lot of strictly positive solutions, which can also be found by the Fourier series. An example is given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{k=1}^\infty e^{\cos(2^kx)/2^k}.$